# Interpret seaborn pairplots

Tags: python

For the figure given below, generated by `seaborn.pairplot`, I am trying to describe what the plots says.

[image]

I can say for sure that Label 0 is well concentrated.  What does the diagonal plot say though about the classes?  I just wanted to get a gauge as to what information can be interpreted from the plots, without knowing anything else?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is significant overplotting here (orange on top of blue, green on top of orange on top of blue, etc.). You may wish to set the `alpha` parameter to be lower (say 0.25) to get a visual sense of the extent of class overlap.

With that said, I think you could see that:

- There is little evidence of class separation between groups 0, 1 and 2 - there is significant overlap between them.
- Group 2 appears to contain a wider range of `feat1` values than the other two groups.
- Group 0 is tightly clustered around about `(0, -1)`.